# How do I get $T(n) \leq cn^{lg(3)}-2n$ from $T(n) \approx n^{lg(3)}$?

Tags: algorithms

I'm learning "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition
By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein", referencing the [solution](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eajl213/CLRS/Ch4.pdf) to Exercise 4.4-1

I know the following equation gives the running time of the algorithm on the whole input of size n.

$n\sum\limits_{i=0}^{lg(n)}(3/2)^i=n\frac{(3/2)^{lg(n)}-1)}{.5}\approx n^{lg(3)}$

How do I get the following inductive hypothesis from the equation above

$T(n) \leq cn^{lg(3)}-2n$

Comment: You don’t. You have to be creative.

Comment: The first equation evaluates exactly to $2n(n^{\lg 3-1}-1)$, so what more do you want ?